# Boot Into OS Depending on physical switch position

Tags: boot, noobs, bootloader, multiboot

Does anyone know of a boot-loader existing, or if NOOBS can interpret the position of a switch/read GPIO pins at boot then pick the partition to boot into based on what it reads?  E.g. Switch in position 1 boots into Raspbian, 2 into OpenElec, etc... I know that you can change the autoboot file for noobs but that would require it to be booted already to change it before rebooting.

I know you can get SD Card Switches  like [this](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/sd-cards-and-adaptors/sd-card-readers/2-in-1-sd-card-dual-system-switcher-for-raspberry-pi) but I'm thinking 4 OS's (One for desktop, one for media, one for RetroPi and one for pen-testing) so that could get silly linking 3 of those together, and thus not portable. Along the hardware route though, has anyone had experience of making an SD switch?  I'd imagine soldering your own at home could introduce a lot of latency without access to PCB Printing.

Any ideas would be cool, just need to find out before I order lots of new parts for a project :)